# MVC - Model-View communication

Tags: java, model-view-controller

First of all I want to say that I searched a lot, but I found a lot of different solutions on the internet that contradict each other.

To simplify my question, I'll use an example. Let's say I want to generate a map for a 2D game using the MVC design pattern :

**MapView.java**

```java
public class MapView extends TheViewComponent {
    public MapView() {
        // Create the view
    }
}
```

**MapController.java**

```java
public class MapController {
    // …

    public MapController(Map map, MapView mapView) {
        this.map = map;
        this.mapView = mapView;
    }
}
```

**Map.java**

```java
public class Map {
    public void generate() {
        // Should create tiles in my MapView.
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```java
public class Main {
    public Main() {
        Map map = new Map();
        MapView mapView = new MapView();
        MapController mapController = new MapController(map, mapView);
    }
}
```

In the `generate()` method (Map.java), I don't understand how I can to update the view. In my Map class I don't have the reference to the controller or the view.

- Should I pass the view to the  model with `new Map(mapView)` ? (seems weird…)
- Should I generate the map in the Controller ? But if that's true, let's say if I have a list of tiles in my `Map.java`, and let's say for the example that I have operations to do on Tile and TileView (like my map). I want to store an `ArrayList<Tile>` and not an `ArrayList<TileController>`… So this second solution seems weird too…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain model `Map` should only hold the structure of the map and should make it accessible by the outer world (e.g. `getTiles()`). Then, the view should use that domain data to render a map accordingly.

For manipulation, the controller should provide entry points for the relevent actions and dispatch them to a service layer that in turn does update the domain model.

Comment: And should I put the `map.generate()` and `mapView.update()` in the `Controller`, or in `Main` ?

Comment: I am not sure what the purpose of `Main` is in your context. From my perception, `Main` should only launch the application. The controllers provide the API for the outer world to interact with your application (e.g. a view could provide a button that then calls such action, or a REST API call could trigger such controller action.) The controller is mostly responsible for handling such request. That could involve data manipulation, but normally you would want a service layer for the actual operations on the data and a data-layer to store / retrieve data.

Comment: So `map.generate()` should be part of a service layer or controller-internal. `mapView.update()` should be called from the controller. Actually, I would argue, that `generate()` should not be part of the model itself, but a service function that creates a map. The `Map` should only hold the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is an architectural pattern with the goal to separate responsibilities

**Model**
This is your business layer (domain and logic) and should not have any say on how you are going to "view" the data. For example the Model provides you an object/list/map with the information to be displayed.

Tip: here your code should not rely on web frameworks or HTTP Servlet API

**View**
This is the layer responsible to render the data in the User Interface: it should not include business rules or security, but only presentation logic

**Controller**
It sits in the middle: it dispatches the request to the relevant Model and forward the outcome to the appropriate View